# Is there a better way I can import/export a library of components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a component library where I use `index.ts` to import/export the components. As I build components, I have to add more imports along with more exports. The work grows by `O(n)`.

Is there a way I can export all imported files? That way I would only have to do import the components, which would cut the work in half. These components will be named imports such as `import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo } from '@library'`

**index.ts**

```js
// Imports: Components
import ComponentOne from '../src/components/ComponentOne';
import ComponentTwo from '../src/components/ComponentTwo';
import ComponentThree from '../src/components/ComponentThree';
import ComponentFour from '../src/components/ComponentFour';

// Exports
export {
  ComponentOne,
  ComponentTwo,
  ComponentThree,
  ComponentFour,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also look at Re-exporting/Aggregating per [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#re-exporting_aggregating)

Syntax would be cleaner i.e:

```
export { ComponentOne } from '../src/components/ComponentOne';
```

Comment: I switched my components from default exports to name exports + this. This saved me a few lines in the component file by removing redundancy using `export const componentOne` + trimmed half of my import/exports by exporting while importing in `index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver#readme) which can simplify the `require/import` paths in your project. For example, instead of using complex relative paths like `../../../../utils/my-utils`, you can write utils/my-utils. It will allow you to work faster since you won't need to calculate how many levels of the directory you have to go up before accessing the file.

```
// Use this:
import MyUtilFn from 'utils/MyUtilFn';
// Instead of that:
import MyUtilFn from '../../../../utils/MyUtilFn';

// And it also work with require calls
// Use this:
const MyUtilFn = require('utils/MyUtilFn');
// Instead of that:
const MyUtilFn = require('../../../../utils/MyUtilFn');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `export` from the same file you're working on like,

```js
export default ComponentOne;
```

No need to create another file for just export & import like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `babel-plugin-wildcard` if you not want to maintain an index.js file.

```sh
# install plugin
npm i babel-plugin-wildcard --save-dev
```

Add wildcard to plugin section in your babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['wildcard'], // <-- add this
};
```

Usage:

```
|- index.js
|- dir
    |- a.js
    |- b.js
```

index.js:

```js
import * as Items from './dir';

console.log(Items.A);
console.log(Items.B);
```

Check plugin GitHub page [here](https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-wildcard) for more information.